# Trigonometric equation for double angle

Tags: trigonometry

Can anyone direct me to a basic method solving this equation:

$$ [\sin(2x)+(\sqrt{3} \cos2x)]^2 \ - \ 5 \ = \ \cos(30º-2x) $$

Comment: yes it is correct

Comment: could you demonstrate the solution of LHS

Comment: i am sorry but LHS| has the sin 2x in the square portion

Comment: it is the whole square of sin 2x+((3)^1/2)cos 2x

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\cos(30^o - 2 x) = \cos(30^o) \cos(2x) + \sin(30^o) \sin(2 x) = \ldots$.  Let this be $u$, express the left side in terms of $u$, and solve for $u$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\sin 2x + \sqrt{3}\cos 2x = 2\left(\frac{1}{2}\sin 2x + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos 2x\right) = 2(\sin 30\sin 2x + \cos 30\cos 2x) = 2\cos(30-2x)$$

So let $y = \cos (30-2x)$.

Your equation becomes $$4y^2 - 5 = y$$

Solve for $y$ and deduce the value of $x$ from that.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee the question I see says $[\sin 2x + \sqrt{3}\cos 2x]^2$ and as I've proved, that's $4y^2$. I don't know how you've come up with $\sin 2x + (\sqrt{3}\sin 2x)^2$

Comment: Sorry, probably problem with page loading